# Check if a file has not been selected in an input file when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, file, if-statement, input

I have created a form that contains some inputs including one of type file and I want to check if when sending the form there are files selected or not and set the createObjectUrl to "" hat's what I have but when I send the form it generates the error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.

```
submit.addEventListener('click', function(procesarImagen){
    procesarImagen.preventDefault();
    cont_rev_add.style.display = "none"
    rev_add.style.display = "initial"
    const archivo = input_file.files
    const PrimerArchivo = archivo[0]
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(PrimerArchivo)
    if (!archivo || !archivo.length) {
        objectURL.URL.createObjectURL("")
    }
    review.push({
        name: input_name.value + "<br> <span id='title_t'>" + input_profession.value + "</span>",
        texto_review: input_review.value,
        img_review: objectURL
    }
    ) 
  })


I have tried modifying the if condition to check the length of the input and I hope to find the solution to this problem.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is this a typo?

Here:

```
 objectURL.URL.createObjectURL("")
```

Did you mean:

```
 objectURL = URL.createObjectURL("")
```

#### This would be a better design:

```
const archivo = input_file.files
const PrimerArchivo = archivo[0]
let objectURL = PrimerArchivo ? URL.createObjectURL(PrimerArchivo) : null;
if (!objectURL) {
    objectURL = "";
}
```

Comment: the if does not prove anything

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, the error could be caused by the following line:

==> objectURL.URL.createObjectURL("")

This line is attempting to create a new object URL, but the argument passed to createObjectURL() is an empty string. This is likely causing the error.

To fix this issue, you can add a condition to check whether a file has been selected before creating the object URL. Here's an updated version of the code that includes this check:

```js
submit.addEventListener('click', function(procesarImagen){
  procesarImagen.preventDefault();
  cont_rev_add.style.display = "none"
  rev_add.style.display = "initial"
  const archivo = input_file.files
  const PrimerArchivo = archivo[0]
  let objectURL = ''
  if (PrimerArchivo) {
    objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(PrimerArchivo)
  }
  review.push({
    name: input_name.value + "<br> <span id='title_t'>" + input_profession.value + "</span>",
    texto_review: input_review.value,
    img_review: objectURL
  })
})
```